# Bootstrap "hidden.bs.modal" fired but handler won't work

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have registered this short handler to my modal dialog and i want a  is stop playing when i close the dialog:

```
window.Js = {
    // hidden.bs.registration
    registerCloseModalHandler: function (modalId) {
        $(modalId).on("hidden.bs.modal",
            function (e) {
                $("#wavAduioPlayer").src = "";  // <-- BREAKPOINT
            });
    },

    // Button onclick event works
    stopPlayer: function() {
        $("#wavAduioPlayer").src = "";
    };
};
```

The registration of `registerCloseModalHandler` is fine and is set (Checked with DevTools)

The  tag looks like:

```
<audio id="#wavAduioPlayer" src="SomeStreamUrl" preload="none" controls>
```

When i close the dialog the execution hits the breakpoint but the `src` is not set to `""`.

I have check the functionality with a close `<button onclick="Js.stopPlayer()" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>`. And this works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#wavAduioPlayer")` returns a jQuery object. You can't access the `src` attribute the vanilla javascript way. Try:

```
$("#wavAduioPlayer").attr('src', '');
```

Or you could convert the object back to a native DOM element:

```
$("#wavAduioPlayer").get(0).src = "";
```

Comment: Okay that works. But why the button onclick work with ```<button onclick="Js.stopPlayer()" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>```